# Parse error with php script code

Tags: php

i have this code and all time i get same error

```
error_reporting(0);
$file = basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']).'.scan';
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
    $myFile = "ip_up.txt";

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $port1 = $_POST['port3'];
    $port2 = $_POST['port4'];
    $ofile = @fopen($file, "r");

    if ($ofile) {
        while (!feof($ofile)) {
            $ip1 = fgets($ofile, 2048);
            $ip = trim($ip1);

            for($i=$port1;$i<$port2+1;$i++) {
                $tB = microtime(true);
                $fP = fSockOpen($ip, $i, $errno, $errstr, 1);
                $tA = microtime(true);
                if (!$fP) {
                    echo $ip.":".$i." – down";
                } else {
                    echo $ip.":".$i." – ".round((($tA – $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms";
                    fwrite($fh,$ip."\r\n");
                }
                echo "<br>";
                flush();
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="ip_up.txt">Download</a>';
}
else die('error');
?>
```

it gives me this error in line 20

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

i tried to put ' ' in line 20..but it dosend work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
round((($tA – $tB)
```

I think that you want to subtract them, so use this:

```
round((($tA - $tB)
```

It's a very minor difference, but you are not using the correct dash.

Comment: i tried but it need time to accept the best answer..
thank you again

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized that.  You're welcome.  Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Add :

```
$t = $tA - $tB;
echo $ip.":".$i." – ".round((($t) * 1000), 0)." ms";
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.Please accept the answer as suggested by 'Anonymous'.